# signif doesn't give me the correct number of significant digits in R

Tags: r, rounding, significant-digits

I want to round my data with significant digits. Therefore I am using `signif` to achieve that.

For example:

```
signif(0.0054324, digits=2)
[1] 0.0054
```

However, I realised that there are some cases where `signif` doesn't work as I expected.

```
signif(1003.04, digits=3)
[1] 1000

signif(1005.04, digits=3)
[1] 1010
```

As you can see, in the previous examples, it seems that it is using `ceiling` or just giving me integers, without any digits.

Note that I don't want to work with `round` because I have some cases like this (see example below) and I don't want 0s.

```
round(0.000000054324, digits=2)
[1] 0
```

For that case, `signif` gives me exactly what I want.

```
signif(0.000000054324, digits=2)
[1] 5.4e-08
```

Does anyone have any idea about how can I fix that when I use "big" numbers? (Since it works perfectly with small ones). Or if you know any other method.

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Maybe it would be worth giving a specification of what you want, because it doesn't seem to match the usual definition of "significant digits". It seems like a custom function that rounds if numbers are bigger than 1, or uses `signif()` otherwise might be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little function should give you the results you are looking for. It works by only applying `signif` to the fractional part of your number, while preserving the integer part.

```r
mysignif <- function(x, digits = 3) {
  x %/% 1 + signif(x %% 1, digits)
} 

mysignif(0.0054324, digits=2)
#> [1] 0.0054

mysignif(1003.04, digits=3)
#> [1] 1003.04

mysignif(1005.04, digits=3)
#> [1] 1005.04

mysignif(0.000000054324, digits=2)
#> [1] 5.4e-08

mysignif(1.0005433, digits = 3)
#> [1] 1.000543
```

Answer (score 1):

From `?signif`:

> For numeric x, `signif(x, dig)` is the same as `round(x, dig - ceiling(log10(abs(x))))`

When `dig > ceiling(log10(abs(x))))` this leads to negative numbers in `round()`, and thus you get the rounding of your large numbers.

I would fix it like this, by limiting `dig - ceiling(log10(abs(x))))` to 0:

```r
my_signif <- function(x, digits = 4) {
  
  round(x, pmax(digits - ceiling(log10(abs(x))), 0))
  
}  



my_signif(0.0054324, digits=2)
#> [1] 0.0054
my_signif(0.000000054324, digits=2)
#> [1] 5.4e-08
my_signif(1003.04, digits=3)
#> [1] 1003
my_signif(1005.04, digits=3)
#> [1] 1005
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>